# What would be some consequences if $\pi + e$ was proven to be algebraic vs transcendental over $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: transcendental-numbers

What would be some consequences if $\pi + e$ was proven to be algebraic vs transcendental over $\Bbb Q$?  I just read that this is an open problem and I wanted to see what some farther reaching consequences would be if this were proven to be algebraic or transcendental.

Comment: I siuppose the most interesting consequences would be that the methods used in the proof advanced our understanding.

Answer (score 7):

If it were algebraic, that would disprove Schanuel's conjecture.  Which would be a shame, because lots of nice things follow from Schanuel's conjecture.  However,  it's almost certain that $\pi + e$ is transcendental, even though we can't prove it, so I wouldn't worry too much about that possibility.

Comment: How do you measure "almost certain" if can't prove it?

Comment: There are lots of conjectures that we don't know how to prove, but most experts in the field are pretty confident of.

Comment: **Why** they are "pretty confident" if can't prove it. I simply don't understand. Really.

Comment: So from Schanuel's conjecture, would $\pi e$, $\pi^e$, $pi^\pi$, $e^e$, and $e^\pi^2$ also be transcendental?